# Quotient groups

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to figure out the order of each element of the following group:
$$U(15)/H = {H,2H,7H,11H},$$  $H = \langle[4]\rangle$

I am trying to find order of $7H$, I started by writing that $7H={7,13}$ and $7H^{2}={4,4}$, and $7H^{4}={1,1}$ But the identity element of $U(15)/H$ is H, isn't it. But 7H to any power is not equal to H! Or am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No, $(7H)^2=4H=H$, which is the identity of $U(15)/H$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews isn't $(7H)^{2}={4,4}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how coset products work. Given two subsets, $A,B$ of $G$, $AB=\{ab\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$. In particular then, since $7H=\{[7],[13]\}$, you have:

$$(7H)^2 = (7H)(7H)=\{[7][7],[7][13],[13][7],[13][13]\}=\{[4],[1]\}=H$$